# the R (programming language) library for random variable operations

Tags: probability, statistics

Does anyone know if the R library provides tools to perform some basic algebraic operations on r.v?

Matlab doesn't have this (as far as I know), but if anyone knows about the existence of an extension to do this it would be great.

Thanks for your kindness

Answer (score 1):

If by "algebraic operations on [random variables]" you mean computer algebra systems (CAS) which allows computation and manipulation (i.e. symbolic computation) of mathematical expressions, then I think there are some tools available that interface with other software. Examples are the `rSymPy`and `Ryacas` packages.

If not, R supports regular algebraic operations on realized random variables. E.g. consider the following R code:

```
rv1 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 4.5, sd = 3) # Draw 1000 normal distributed values
rv2 <- rchisq(1000, df = 1)
new.rv <- cos(log(rv1^2 + 5))*rv2 # Some weird transformation
hist(new.rv)  # Plot a histogram of the new r.v.
```

Comment: Oh no I meant sum,product,inverse.. operations. Nothing symbolic

Comment: Well, then the answer is affirmative. I have edited my answer.

Comment: what about taking the sum (or product) of two r.v of != distribution? Can R handle this?

Comment: Yes. E.g. if `X <- rnorm(100)` and `Y <- rchisq(100,df=5)`, then `X*Y`is perfectly valid. See `hist(X*Y)` or `print(X*Y)`. But remember, this is just realizations of distributions! Not the actual distributions.

Comment: Great! Can you please provide me with a good R-documentation for this matter?
And do you have an idea about the algorithm used behind? (Monte-carlo, Mellin transform..?)
Many thanks

Comment: This is basic R language. I can't help but think we are misunderstanding each other. The `+` and `*` is regular floating point addition and multiplication. For the simulation of the values run e.g. `?rnorm`.

Comment: I am looking for getting the distribution of the r.v obtained after these operations, not just realizations of distributions

Comment: @aflous Well, you can approximate it quite well by simulation very easily in `R`.

Comment: an example maybe? I'm not used to R
(Do you know if Matlab has this feature?)

Comment: @aflous I have updated my example. The histogram (or the kernel density estimate) is an estimate of the pdf of `new.rv` which is a weird transformation of the two random variables. You can approximate the true pdf arbitrarily well by increasing the number of simulations (1000 in this case).

Comment: weird transformation? Can you tell me more about it (if you know of course)? What type of transformation is it used on this algorithm? Mellin, Fourier...?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by r.v. But all you seem to want is to be to be able to calculate the sum, product, ratio, mean, standard deviation, etc. That's pretty straight forward in R (also I suggest you run R in Rstudio because you can save your graphical plots.) Anyway, how about some data.

R is a pretty straight forward language as you can see all your operations are done in parentheses.

> x = c(1:10) # where c is for concatenating # so this prints out 10 numbers from 1 to 10.
>
> x
>
> x = c(1, 3, 8, 13, 21) # So this prints out specific numbers. 
>   x
>   Now, lets work with the data.
>
> sum(x), so R just computed the sum of all the numbers in the set. 
>   [1] 46 # That's 1^2 + 3^2 + 8^2 + 13^2 + 21^2

## What if I want the sum of the squared numbers?

> sum(x^2) # computes 1^2 + 3^2 + 8^2 + 13^2 + 21^2
>   [1] 684
>
> ## another way to do that ...
>
> y = x^2 
>   sum(y)
>   [1] 684

You want the median?

> median(x)
>   [1] 9.2
>
> ## How about the range?
>
> range(x) 
>   [1] 1 21 # so the range is 1 to 21.
>
> ## You can get a lot of information by just running.
>
> summary(x)

## You want to use R like a calculator?

> 2 * 3 
>   3^2 
>   prod(1:5) # Just calculated 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120 or 5! 
>   [1] 120

## Check your variables:

> ls() 
>   [1] x y
>
> ## remove a variable.
>
> rm(y)
>
> ## variable y is gone

Now let's make a data frame which is basically an excel spreadsheet of columns. 
I will call this data frame df.

> df <- data.frame(x) # or df = data.frame(x)

## Lets look at our dataframe in real time.

> View(x) 
>   Now let's add a new column to it, and call it y.
>
> df$y = 2 * (df$x)^2 + 3
>
> ## as you can see what is in column y is now what is in x squared times 2 and then plus 3. Now, let's graph this. # Note: The dollar signs refer to columns within the data frame.

## Essentially I am graphing the function: y = 2 * (x^2) + 3

## using real data points relative to each other.

## Let's make the graph.

> plot(df$x, df$y, main = "My first Graph in R", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", col = "darkorchid4", pch = 16)
>
> ## Everything except for df$x & df$y are just aesthetics.

## Now let us fit a spline cure to it. It won't be perfect but its better than a straight line which purely doesn't fit the dataset.

> lines(smooth.spline(df$x, df$y))

## Alright now let's calculate the area under this curve with respect to x given

## which is from 1 to 21. We don't have to specify the range. R already knows what it is.

Google how to install a package in R or in Rstudio click tools, install packages, and then type pracma in the package, and then load the package.

> library(pracma) # We need pracma to give us the function trapz which will calculate the area under our curve trapezoidal area approximation.
>
> trapz(df$x, df$y) 
>   [1] 6490

That's a pretty good approximation of (from 1 to 21) ∫(2x^2 + 3)dx 
= 6233 + (1 / 3) 
If I had less gaps in x, the integral would be great, and yes, R can integrate functions numerically.

> fx <- function(x) {2 * x^2 + 3}
>
> integrate(fx, lower = 1, upper = 21)
>   6233.333 with absolute error < 6.9e-11

As you can see R can do a lot of things, and I haven't even shown you all the statistics it can do. One of the great things about R is that it is very useful for data-mining which is why many bioinformaticians use it. A function that takes 21 lines or so to write in C, can be executed in R in one line without having to make your own function.

By the way, in R read up on the plot function. See what arguments it accepts.

> ?plot # notice the question mark.

## To learn R I suggest looking at the data provided in R and doing simple examples to see what happens.

> data(Indometh) # these are built in datasets. 
>   data(women)
>   women
>
> ## or just ...
>
> data()
>
> ## and scroll through the datasets.

If you doubt R's capability to do something. You are wrong. It can do it in 1 to 3 lines of code.

## Now I'm going to give you some free books on R which are legal because they # are distributed by R which is free software and the books are under the GNU license so learn yourself something. R distributes these books

Using R for Introductory Statistics:
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Verzani-SimpleR.pdf

An R book that isn't a lot of fluff! Solving Epidemiology problems with R!
ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/doc/contrib/Epicalc_Book.pdf

Comment: Can somebody fix this formatting? The dollar signs are off!